# application.js get required as html in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This line on my application layout

```
javascript_include_tag 'application.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

get interpreted as and order to load a html resource on prodution when clearly is an script.

[image]

[image]
I was expecting application.js get loaded on browser, but it show Error 500. I suspect that browser erroneously expects that applicaciton.js be an html resource.

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require add_fields
//
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

 if ($('li.active').html() != undefined) {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');}

 $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: I strongly doubt that the browser is sending a request for `text/html` - you can check that by just changing to the request tab in the web inspector. But your web server is responding with  `text/html` - probaly some sort of built in error page. If I had to guess I would guess that your server isn't correctly setup to serve static assets.

Comment: Thanks @max. I will edit the question to append the request tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As formerly stated by @max, were an error on application.js that got corrected when I removed the following lines

```
//= require add_fields
//
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

 if ($('li.active').html() != undefined) {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');}

 $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');

});
```

appplication.js corrected

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```